# HTML Dropdown Menu Selections within URL

Tags: html, web, select, drop-down-menu

I'm not really sure how to ask this question, or whether it's even possible. I have previously built an android app that searched for data within a specific webpage and returned the data to the app. This app worked perfectly for over a year until the website in question performed a site wide session of prettying itself up, and in doing so, inadvertently breaking my app.

Within the new designed website, a dropdown menu has been added, which has several selections:

'Show20News',
'Show50News',
'Show100News',
'Show250News',
'Show500News'

The default selection is 'Show20News', and what I want is to make a selection of 'Show500News' instead. However, I want to append the selection to the URL, rather than manually selecting it. I have contacted the websites web team who just can't seem to understand what I am asking for, hence my visit here.

The website link:

https://www.londonstockexchange.com/news?tab=news-explorer&results=500&indices=AXX&sources=RNS&period=daily

What I'd like to achieve is adding the 'Show500News' selection from the dropdown menu to the end of the above URL, to avoid the manual process of getting the same results.

If you take a look at the source code of the link above, you will notice that there is no code that represents the possible selections. It is this that has me stumped. If possible I'm hoping that someone maybe able to nudge me in the right direction, or at least tell me if and why it's not possible. Thanks.